# Android Studio expands Activity name in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgraded my project from Eclipse to Android Studio.

Everything is working, including different flavors (in Eclipse I had an ANT script that auto-generated the sourcecode for the different flavors).

I can also generate the different signed APK's. And these all work on the device.
Also uploading these APK's to GooglePlay is no problem.

User also get these updates, but after the update they need to re-create the shortcut to the app on the home screen. The old shortcut is removed.

I believe this is due to the fact that "Android Studio" modifies stuff in the AndroidManifest.xml when generating the APK.

In Eclipse source, in Android studio source and when I inspect the Eclipse generated APK I have the following (with the name being .StartUpActivity) :

```
<activity android:name=".StartUpActivity" >
   <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

However, when I look into the generated apk from Android Studio this is modified to :

```
<activity android:name="be.abc.android.StartUpActivity">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So the name has been changed from *.StartUpActivity* to *be.abc.android.StartUpActivity*.
In the end, this is the same path but I believe the shortcut just looks at the name .StartUpActivity, and decides it is no longer available and removes the shortcut....

Can I fix this in someway that the shortcuts don't get deleted. Or that Android Studio doesn't mess with the shortened package names in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as soon as you modify the launcher manifest entry, the shortcut has to be recreated. To avoid such issue, you can make use of [`activity-alias`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html). A step-by-step guide can be found [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2014/01/16/preserve-your-launchers-use-activity-alias/).

Comment: This gives the same problem, but now in the activity-alias instead of the activity :-(


I now have <activity-alias android:name=".StartUpActivity" android:targetActivity="be.gps.android.StartUpActivity"> in my AndroidManifest.xml

But in the compiled APK android studio has changed this to <activity-alias android:name="be.gps.android.StartUpActivity" android:targetActivity="be.gps.android.StartUpActivity">